PuTTY sends Ctrl+Shift+6 as Ctrl+6
I am using nano on a remote computer through PuTTY, and when trying to search backward, Ctrl+Shift+6 appears to be having the same effect as Ctrl+6, i.e., Mark Set/Unset.

I searched and couldn't find key mapping options regarding Ctrl+Shift combinations

Is there another command to search backward in nano?

Do those key bindings work outside of nano (e.g. can you copy/paste via Ctrl+Shift+C/V)? I've never encountered this problem, but can't recall if I'm using the default PuTTY profile or if I customized it - the only other places that would affect this AFAIK would be the Nano RC file, the shell's RC file, or termcap's.

This is on a newly installed PC, and the remote computer has not changed. I have previously been able to search backwards on nano via PuTTY. So it looks like an issue with the PuTTY profile.

If PuTTY is installed on Windows, please post the output from exported Registry key HKCU\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\<name>, where <name> is either the saved profile name for that connection or the default profile (if the former, please anonymize it, removing the connection and login info). This will allow a comparison to be done - try this customized PuTTY profile I use, and if it resolves the issue, a diff compare can be done.

I diff'ed the two profiles and what I think could be relevant different ones are: TerminalType of xterm (yours is xterm-256color, CtrlShiftCV of none (yours is implicit. (I am ok with not using Ctrl-C to copy to the clipboard.) Other different ones include TerminalSpeed, HideMousePtr, CurType, ScrollBar`, etc. If you need the whole list I can add that to my question.

I should have verified the nano hotkeys - did you configure a custom hotkey, as searching backwards is Ctrl+B / Alt+B? xterm-256color is recommended for a colorized shell (I use Oh-My-Zsh) and CtrlShiftCV is for using Ctrl+Shift+C/V, but this option is disabled by default (see 4.11.4.2 in the PuTTY Help pages: Open: Settings → Window → Highlight: Selection → Click ? in upper right of window → Click: "Ctrl + Shift + {C,V}")

Mmm... interesting. Previously I Googled and all the responses I got (eghttps://monovm.com/blog/how-to-search-in-nano-editor/) were Ctrl-Shift-6 to search up. Now I see https://keycombiner.com/collections/nano/ says it's Ctrl-q. Ctrl-B seems to behave like moving one character left for me. I didn't configure anything. Everything was at default. Looks more complex than first thought. Ctrl-G`` for my version (Ubuntu 22) is Help and it shows there is no command to search backward! I have to use vim` to search what I need in my log files.

Link I provided is from nano's official site [Nano-Editor.org], so my guess is KeyCombiner's site hasn't been updated in a while - Ctrl+Q does open the backwards search function versus Ctrl+W for the forward search function, however Ctrl+B searches backwards one result at a time, showing the backwards search function every time, whereas Alt+B does an automated backwards search without requiring the dialog of Ctrl+B. Screenshot of nano on an Ubuntu 22.04.4 VM [bottom] and nano on OpenWrt 23.05 in PuTTY

(Cont'd...) My hunch is some sites, like KeyCombiner's, haven't been updated in line with updates made to nano's functionality, as a lot of changes have been made to nano over the past several years (for example, many config parameters, including those for nanorc, have either been depreciated or fully disabled and not recognized because they've been depreciated)
